# transaction log backup on SQL server

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I am using log shipping as DR for my organisation.

For the particular time like morning 4 to 5'o clock `.wrk` files are falling instead of `.trn` file and that particular file take too much time to copy.

I configured log shipping for 570 databases in 4 instances in DR server.

Please suggest.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific? What have you configured exacty (possible example). Which exact files are **fail**ing? (I am assuming you mean failing and not **fall**ing). Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

**.wrk** files are just temporary extension names, while log files are being copied. If log is small enough you wont even notice that change, but in your case it is notable. 
Basically this is way of sql server ensuring that log that has being copied wont be accidentally restored by LSRestore job or by a manual restore.
As soon as log has been copied successfully it will change into **.trn**.

I dont know anything about your SQL, hardware and network specifications but having 570 transaction log backups in a span of one hour once in 24h could cause overhead on disk IO.
Check the log file size, perhaps adding to the schedule one more LS during 24h span would be beneficial (lower tran log size).

Comment: Well explained. Adding on to it, seems at that time his environment generates a bigger log file or faces a Network latency.

Answer (score 0):

The `wrk` files are created while the the LS process (sqllogship.exe) pulls the file from the primary to your secondary. Once it copies the file the last step of that process it will rename it to `trn`.

If the process is failing fully copy over the file you have to look at network issues. However, the job that handles that copying should have clear output history as to why it failing. You have to troubleshoot from that output is showing you.

I have had one client where we had to write our own copy process because the single-threaded method that `sqllogship.exe` does was not sufficient to keep up with the work, mostly due to the client's network between the production and DR site.